# start emacs with org-agenda-list AND todo items

Tags: org-agenda, hooks

Is there any way to start emacs with both weekly agenda and todo list at startup? Similar to Doom Emacs shortcut `<SPACE> - o - a - a - n` (Agenda and all TODO's).

I can't seem to find a way to do this and both of these will overwrite the previous if used together, in separate windows:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'org-todo-list)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'org-agenda-list)
```

Comment: See the `Block Agenda` section in [Custom agenda views](https://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-Agenda-Views.html#Custom-Agenda-Views).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, the solution is pretty simple:

```
(defun emacs-startup-screen ()
  "Display the weekly org-agenda and all todos."
  (org-agenda nil "n"))
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook #'emacs-startup-screen)
```

Instead of the named function `emacs-startup-screen`, you can also use a lambda function like `(lambda () (org-agenda nil "n"))`, but using lambdas in hooks is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you. I have used "dashboard" since then, but this worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

My solution, which pops up the org agenda when running `emacs` with no file names as args, but doesn't interfere when I want to quickly open a file with `emacs filename [filename [...]]`, is to put this in my `init.el`:

```lisp
(setq initial-buffer-choice (lambda () ;; startup routine
                              ;; If no file is open in any buffer
                              (if (not (seq-some (function (lambda (buf) (buffer-file-name buf)))
                                                 (buffer-list)))
                                  ;; open org agenda and show it
                                  (progn (ignore) ;; TODO: fetch gcal
                                         (org-agenda nil "n")
                                         (delete-other-windows)
                                         (get-buffer "*Org Agenda*"))
                                ;; else show default (show all, and select last)
                                (seq-some 'identity (reverse (mapcar
                                                              (function (lambda (buf) (if (buffer-file-name buf) buf nil)))
                                                              (buffer-list))))
                                )))
```